# Что означает auto mode в update-alternatives --config java?

Tags: linux, java, openjdk

Что означает `auto mode` в `update-alternatives --config java?`
Вот, что нашел в man, но это ситуацию не особо разъяснило.

> automatic mode
> When a link group is in automatic mode, the
> alternatives system ensures that the links in the  group  point  to
> the  highest  priority alternative appropriate for the group.
>
> manual mode
> When a link group is in manual mode, the alternatives
> system will not make any changes to the system administrator's
> settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

вкратце, это механизм выбора пакетов по приоретам (для апдейтов, допустим). Ну, например, для java cуществуют по крайней мере 4 возможные для установки по дефолту реализации:

- OpenJDK
- Oracle Java
- IBM Java
- GNU Compiler

автоматический режим выберет ту реализацию, которая считается системой "самой правильной"

ручной - оставит ту, которую ты указал изначально.

я бы советовал использовать автоматическую, а ручной режим выбирать только если ты точно знаешь, что твой софт не работает, например, с OpenJDK, а только с Oracle Java

Comment: Что за ручной и автоматический режимы?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/613016/removing-oracle-jdk-and-re-configuring-update-alternatives короче ты просто выбираешь, система за тебя решает какую яву ставить или ты сам решаешь. Тебе для чего вообще это нужно? какую проблему решаешь?

Comment: Проблемы никакой нет, просто любопытно было, для чего эти режимы.

Comment: раньше например phpstorm не работал в убунте без oracle jdk, потом они стали свою яву поставлять, кажется. потому и спросил.

Comment: *это механизм выбора пакетов по приоретам (для апдейтов, допустим)* — вообще-то «альтернативы» — это механизм выбора **файлов**, а не пакетов. и, соответственно, к «апдейтам» (видимо, пакетов?) не имеет (прямого) отношения.

Answer (score 4):

что такое система альтернатив, кратко, но неплохо, изложено в [википедийной статье](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternatives), с которой я рекомендую ознакомиться прежде чем читать дальше.

---

в чём смысл *auto mode* и *manual mode*, попробую объяснить на примере программы *vim*.

- поставили вы свежую систему, и в ней этой программы нет вообще.
- установили вы пакет *vim*. в него входит (в том числе) файл `/usr/bin/vim.basic`, а в послеустановочном скрипте (с помощью программы *update-alternatives*) этот файл регистрируется как *альтернатива* для файла `/usr/bin/vim` с приоритетом 30 (почему именно 30? ну, так сопровождающие пакетов решили). и получается такая цепочка ссылок:

  ```
  /usr/bin/vim → /etc/alternatives/vim → /usr/bin/vim.basic
  ```
- установили вы после этого пакет *vim-gtk*, в который входит (в том числе) файл `/usr/bin/vim.gtk`, а в послеустановочном скрипте этот файл регистрируется как *альтернатива* тому же самому файлу `/usr/bin/vim`, но с приоритетом 50.
- и так как набор альтернатив для файла `/usr/bin/vim` в данный момент находился в «авто-режиме» (*auto mode*), то программой *update-alternatives* (которая была вызвана в послеустановочном скрипте пакета *vim-gtk*) текущей альтернативой выбирается та, которая имеет больший приоритет, т.е., `/usr/bin/vim.gtk`. и получается чуть иная цепочка ссылок:

  ```
  /usr/bin/vim → /etc/alternatives/vim → /usr/bin/vim.gtk
  ```
- а вот если бы перед установкой пакета *vim-gtk* вы запустили `sudo update-alternatives --config vim` и **вручную** выбрали бы вариант `/usr/bin/vim.basic` (и неважно, что он был одним-единственным на тот момент), то набор альтернатив переключился бы на «ручной режим» (*manual mode*), и после установки пакета *vim-gtk* переключения альтернативы бы не произошло, осталась актуальной старая цепочка ссылок:

  ```
  /usr/bin/vim → /etc/alternatives/vim → /usr/bin/vim.basic
  ```

---

где же фиксируются все эти приоритеты, возможные альтернативы, текущий режим (*auto/manual*) для, например, программы *vim*? в файле `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/vim`:

```
manual
/usr/bin/vim

/usr/bin/vim.basic
30
/usr/bin/vim.gtk
50
```

первая строка — режим (*auto* или *manual*), вторая строка — собственно файл, для которого дальше перечислены альтернативы со своими приоритетами.

---

а как вернуть обратно «авто-режим»?

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --auto vim
```

стоит отметить, что «авто-режим» «включается» по умолчанию при регистрации самой первой альтернативы для файла. а «ручной режим» «включается» после того, как с помощью опции `--config имя` программы *update-alternatives* вы **вручную** указали использовать какую-то из альтернатив. (вообще, конечно, можно и без *update-alternatives*, поменть первую строку в файле `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/имя`).