# Как при вводе "python" в терминал запускать самую последнюю версию python? Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, python-2.x

Как сделать так, чтобы при вводе в терминале **python** запускалась не **вторая**, а какая-либо ещё версия интерпретатора? Например, 3.5 или 3.6

То есть как реализовать такую фичу, чтобы когда я вводил `python module.py` в терминале, скрипт запускался с третьей версией python'a, а не со второй?

Comment: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/521123/178576) и [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/551349/178576)

Comment: Но зачем это нужно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Перед тем, как делать всё, что описано далее, внимательно прочтите

**Очень не рекомендуется менять ссылки**. Дело в том, что есть программы, зависимые от старых версий python. И если изменить ссылку на программу, то может возникнуть конфликт импорта библиотек, а если библиотеки всё же найдутся, то не факт, что их устройство не изменилось со сменой версии python, поэтому опасно менять ссылки на стандартные названия. Как быть? Описано в конце.

## Команда ln

Сейчас у меня в каталоге `/usr/bin/` файл `python` ссылается на `python2.7`, а `python3` - на `python3.5`. Я же хочу, чтобы `python` ссылался на `python3.5`, а `python3` ссылался на `python3.6`. Как это реализовать?

Для того, чтобы нам настроить запуск команд по своему усмотрению, можно воспользоваться командой ln. Это команда для создания ссылок. Чтобы вызвать помощь можно набрать в терминале `ln --help`

## Для тех, кто всё равно так хочет

Напишем в терминале следующий код:

```
sudo ln -f -v /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python
# атрибут -f означает, что мы удалим текущую существующую ссылку
# атрибут -v - показать результат выполнения
```

Проверим, что теперь `python` ссылается на `python3.5`. Выполнив `python --version` мы увидим следующее: `Python 3.5.2`

Давайте изменим ссылку для `python3`?

```
sudo ln -f -v /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3
```

Проверяем, что всё сработало корректно:

```
python3 --version # Python 3.6.0+
```

Такой подход плох тем, что мы меняем адреса ссылок у стандартных бинарников, создавая жёсткие ссылки. Это чревато отказом в работе некоторых программ, которые зависимы от старых версий python и запускают интерпретатор с помощью таких строк в начале скрипта:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# или
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

## Создавайте свои ссылки!

Для этого нам поможет атрибут `-s` (символьная ссылка) команды `ln`

Давайте создадим ссылку на `python3.5` с именем `p35`:

```
sudo ln -f -s -v /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/p35
'/usr/bin/p35' -> '/usr/bin/python3.5'
```

Также если мы зайдём в каталог `/usr/bin/` и поищем `p35`, то мы увидим уже не бинарный файл, а файл-ссылку.

Проверим получилось ли у нас сделать ссылку, выполнив в терминале:

```
p35 --version
# Python 3.5.2
```

Отлично!

Comment: Как на счёт добавить вариант "вкрутить в PATH собственную папку внутри домашней и оставить ссылку в ней"?

Comment: @D-side тоже как вариант, кстати. Возможно чуть позже добавлю в ответ

Comment: Есть ещё вариант с псевдонимом в пользовательском .profile: `alias python=python3.5` и ничего не ломает

Comment: А для начала наберите пару команд -- `which python` и `ls -li /usr/bin/pyth*` (/usr/bin/ это если `which` показал, что python лежит в /usr/bin) и внимательно рассмотрите вывод второй (ключик -i покажет inode, разные имена с одинаковыми inode это те самые hard links). Таким образом вы получите представление, что именно и как предлагает вам установленный дистрибутив (и имейте в виду, что все update системы предполагают ту структуру файлов, которую несет дистрибутив, а не ту, что вы сами наваяете)

Comment: @KitScribe, лучше воспользоваться советами  `mymedia` и `D-side`. А этот ответ я бы лучше удалил, т.к. он предлагает замену ссылок/файлов в системных директориях - это может привести к неприятным последствиям. Какой-нибудь неопытный *NIX пользователь воспользовавшись этим ответом может нарушить целостность системы - "nicht gut !"

Comment: Стоит заметить, что указанный способ может быть применим когда нет другого выхода в вашем дистрибутиве linux. В части дистрибутивов есть штатные средства для выбора рабочей версии (такие как eselect в gentoo) и настоятельно рекомендуется пользоваться штатными методами при их наличии. И это не помешало бы отразить в ответе, который претендует на роль дистрибутиво-независимого

Comment: минус за: `sudo ln -f -v ... /usr/bin/python` в ответе -- это [может угробить машину.](https://askubuntu.com/q/488967/3712) (предупреждений в начале ответа недостаточно). Если `alias` не подходит в вашем случае, то можно ещё virtualenv создать и активировать (к примеру, я использую zsh plugin, который активирует virtualenv когда я перехожу внутрь дерева директорий соответствующего проекта (если проект foo, то foo окружение активируется), можно virtualenvwrapper поставить, чтобы полезные утилит для работы с virtualenv получить. Чтобы со множеством версий работать, есть pythonz, pyenv, conda,etc